# Mongo java driver collection.count() returns one extra always

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB replica set of 2 nodes.

A typical document in the collection looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 409,
    status: "active"
    address: [
        { id: 1000012, type: "primary", status: "active" },
        { id: 1000011, type: "primary", status: "inactive" },
        { id: 1000010, type: "primary", status: "inactive" }
    ],
}
```

When I use the [Java MongoDB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/java/) to find the count of a collection, based on some simple filters, I always get 1 extra (e.g., if the actual count is 1299 the result is 1300):

```
db.collection.count({
    "status": "active",
    "address.type": "primary",
    "address.status": "active"
});
```

I read in the official documentation that `collection.count(...)` [can return incorrect results in case of sharded collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters), but mine is not sharded, it is just a replica set.

However, when I `aggregate` the same query and print the sum, it is always correct (1299):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$address" },
    { $match: {
        "status": "active",
        "address.type": "primary",
        "address.status": "active",
    }},
    { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
    { $project: { _id: 0, count: 1 }}
]);
```

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

This matches the aggregation:

`db.collection.count({"address": {$elemMatch:{"status": "active", "type": "primary"}}, status: "active"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query:

```
db.collection.count({
    "status": "active",
    "address.type": "primary",
    "address.status": "active"
});
```

Is not calculating the same as the one with `aggregation`. This one is selecting all documents (not subdocuments) with `status = "active"` and **ANY** address with `type = "primary"` **OR** `status = "active"`.

By your question and comments I assume you have 1300 documents that match that, but at least one of them doesn't match the `address.type` and `address.status` conditions in the same subdocument, thus returning different results when using `$unwind` with the aggregation framework, as in that case those two should match in the same subdocument.

**`WiredTiger` issues after hard crash:**

Just as a reference for others, another infrequent issue is a hard crash when using `WiredTiger`:

If you are using [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) as your storage engine, the issue may be caused by a hard crash that led to an inconsistent state of `db.stats` upon recovery, which are not recalculated automatically after startup, even though the data was recovered successfully. To rebuild them, run [`db.collection.validate(true)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.validate/).

For more on this issues, see:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19052.
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19472.

Comment: Let me check that right away. Thank you for your quick response Danziger

Comment: That was an interesting perspective. I've checked and each id is present exactly once.

Comment: @TeenaGeorge Are you using WiredTiger? If so, you may have had a hard crash which may have led to an inconsistent state of `db.stats`, which are not recalculated automatically after startup. Try running [`db.collection.validate(true)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.validate/) to rebuild them. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19052 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19472.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will check that,however that seems unlikely because I have the same issue in all the three environments(`dev`, `stage` and `production`). I've been able to get the same result for `collection.count(...)` and `aggregation`. I removed the `$unwind` stage from aggregation query and I got the extra one. I don't have a clue as to why, though. I'm certain that there are no duplicates (thanks to the aggregation in your answer)

Comment: @TeenaGeorge Sorry, I didn't read carefully what you were doing, it's probably something simpler than what I though. Please, check my update.

Comment: you are right. If I use `$elemMatch`, I have the correct count: 1299. 

`db.collection.count({"address": {$elemMatch:{"status": "active", "type": "primary"}}, status: "active"});`

I've tested this using `intellishell`. However, if I run the same query from my java API, it gives me 1 extra.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add this query and code?

Comment: I'm so sorry, the java code didn't have the document level status filter.  If it is any consolation, I didn't write this piece of code originally :S. I'm accepting your answer, because it answers the question asked. Thank you again, @Danziger. I've also learnt a bit more on the aggregation, and a tiny bit on wired tiger.